# Is it correct that: $K$ is compact iff every infinite subset of $K$ has an accumulation point in $K$

Tags: general-topology

> Theorem:
>
> $K \subseteq \big< X,d \big> $
>
> $K$ is compact iff every infinite subset of $K$ has an accumulation point in $K$

This theorem is in my notebook, however when I check on the internet it says that

> $K$ is sequentially compact iff every infinite subset of $K$ has an accumulation point in $K$

Comment: "$K$ is sequentially compact iff every infinite subset of $K$ has an accumulation point in $K$" is not true in general.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

But all different versions of compactness — in particular, compactness and sequential compactness — are equivalent for metric spaces!

Comment: So there is nothing wrong to state or use both of them when needed?

Comment: The theorem you stated says that in metric spaces they're in fact equivalent, so, yes, you can use whichever formulation is most convenient for what you're trying to do.